Converting Globular Cluster Nodes Setup to Galaxy Cluster
I'm trying to see if I can take my globular cluster geometry nodes setup and repurpose it for a galaxy cluster. What I hope to do is to take a few model galaxies I had created and replace the subdivided cubes (representing stars in my globular cluster), with those galaxies.
My galaxy models are based off of image planes. Some models contain UV Spheres attached to the model which represent 3D light halos.

Color variations to make the galaxy clusters less uniform would be helpful too.
In addition, after this, I'm considering how I can modify the shape of the clusters so that I can create versions with material on the edges but not on the center, to represent cosmic voids.
How do I make that happen? Thank you!

Clarifications to Comments (let me know if there's anything else I haven't addressed): I do want to exchange the cubes within my geometry nodes setup with my galaxy models (ideally 2-3 of my models used).

You want to replace subdivided cubes (clear so far) with galaxies. What are galaxies? Some bitmaps? Do you want to spawn quads with galaxy textures? It's unlikely anyone will guess what you mean, therefore please clarify.

Is the question simply how to exchange cubes for something else, e.g. galaxies? Or are you asking us how to create multiple variations of galaxies?

In response to the previous two questions (I updated my question as well), my galaxy objects are planes with image textures with UV sphere's attached to represent halos. So to clarify, I do want to exchange the cubes within my geometry nodes setup with my galaxy models (ideally 2-3 of my models used). Let me know if there are any other questions.

You show sort of an advanced node setup, is it really about replacing the cubes with the galaxies? (Just have a "collection info" node connected to the "instance on points")
